# Не могу установить pycld2

Tags: python-3.x

При попытке использования библиотеки polyglot, появилась ошибка No module pycld2. 
При попытке установить эту библиотеку, появилась ошибка, вот её полный стек:

```
Collecting pycld2
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/21/77/8525fe5f147bf2819c7c9942c717c4a79b83f8003da1a3847759fb560909
/pycld2-0.31.tar.gz (14.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 14.3MB 2.5MB/s
Building wheels for collected packages: pycld2
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pycld2 ... error
  Complete output from command D:\Minicanoda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\0DDE~1\
\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z1po7pfn\\pycld2\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read()
.replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d C:\Users\0DDE~1\AppData\Local\Tem
p\pip-wheel-mah2_1i1 --python-tag cp36:
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pycld2
  copying pycld2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pycld2
  running build_ext
  building 'pycld2._pycld2' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visual
studio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for pycld2
  Running setup.py clean for pycld2
Failed to build pycld2
Installing collected packages: pycld2
  Running setup.py install for pycld2 ... error
    Complete output from command D:\Minicanoda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\0DDE~
1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-z1po7pfn\\pycld2\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read
().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\0DDE~1\AppData\Local
\Temp\pip-record-pajd52nw\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pycld2
    copying pycld2\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\pycld2
    running build_ext
    building 'pycld2._pycld2' extension
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visu
alstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "D:\Minicanoda3\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\0DDE~1\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\
\pip-install-z1po7pfn\\pycld2\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n')
;f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\0DDE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-pajd52n
w\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\0DDE~1\AppData\
Local\Temp\pip-install-z1po7pfn\pycld2\
```

Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 2017 года установлен. Видимо, не все библиотеки установил. Но это не точно.

Comment: Какой командой устанавливаете? Через pip или conda?

Comment: через pip. Командой pip install pycld2

Comment: Перевод ошибки           Ошибка: требуется Microsoft Visual C ++ 14.0. Получите его с помощью «Microsoft Visual C ++ Build Tools»: http: //landinghub.visual
studio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools  "Microsoft Visual C ++ Build Tools"

Comment: Я тоже мучился со всякими визуал студио проблема кроется в том что сам питон собран при помощи Microsoft Visual C ++ 2015 года

Comment: снесите Microsoft Visual C ++ 14.0 и установите Microsoft Visual C ++ Build Tools это отдельная штука инсталлеры есть в интернете погуглите

Comment: скачал Visual Studio Community 2017 отсюда: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/815795/Не-могу-установить-pycld2?noredirect=1#comment1296585_815795

Comment: все-равно не получается установить